# Excessive assembly instructions when calling a method

Tags: c#, jit

I'm reading the book [Pro .net Performance](http://www.apress.com/9781430244585/). It states that:

> Below are the typical prologue and epilogue of a managed method
>   compiled to 32-bit machine code (this is not actual production code
>   produced by a JIT-compiler, which employs numerous optimizations
>   discussed in Chapter 10). The method has four local variables, whose
>   storage is allocated at once in the prologue and reclaimed at once in
>   the epilogue:

The books claims this method:

```
int Calculation(int a, int b)
{
  int x = a + b;
  int y = a - b;
  int z = b - a;
  int w = 2 * b + 2 * a;
  return x + y + z + w;
}
```

Will be translated to:

```
; parameters are passed on the stack in [esp+4] and [esp+8]
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
add esp, 16 ; allocates storage for four local variables
mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+8]
add eax, dword ptr [ebp+12]
mov dword ptr [ebp-4], eax
; ...similar manipulations for y, z, w
mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-4]
add eax, dword ptr [ebp-8]
add eax, dword ptr [ebp-12]
add eax, dword ptr [ebp-16] ; eax contains the return value
mov esp, ebp ; restores the stack frame, thus reclaiming the local storage space
pop ebp
ret 8 ; reclaims the storage for the two parameters
```

To test it I created the following class:

```
class TestCall
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestCall testCall=new TestCall();
            int sum=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                sum += testCall.Calculation(5, 6);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
        int Calculation(int a, int b)
        {
            int x = a + b;
            int y = a - b;
            int z = b - a;
            int w = 2 * b + 2 * a;
            return x + y + z + w;
        }
    }
```

When debugging, Visual Studio's **Disassembly** window shows the `Calculation` method:

```
    23:         {
005B2EB8  push        ebp  
005B2EB9  mov         ebp,esp  
005B2EBB  push        edi  
005B2EBC  push        esi  
005B2EBD  push        ebx  
005B2EBE  sub         esp,48h  
005B2EC1  mov         esi,ecx  
005B2EC3  lea         edi,[ebp-38h]  
005B2EC6  mov         ecx,0Bh  
005B2ECB  xor         eax,eax  
005B2ECD  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
005B2ECF  mov         ecx,esi  
005B2ED1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],ecx  
005B2ED4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],edx  
005B2ED7  cmp         dword ptr ds:[12C668h],0  
005B2EDE  je          005B2EE5  
005B2EE0  call        6970CB2D  
005B2EE5  xor         edx,edx  
005B2EE7  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],edx  
005B2EEA  xor         edx,edx  
005B2EEC  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],edx  
005B2EEF  xor         edx,edx  
005B2EF1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],edx  
005B2EF4  xor         edx,edx  
005B2EF6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],edx  
005B2EF9  xor         edx,edx  
005B2EFB  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],edx  
005B2EFE  nop  
    24:             int x = a + b;
005B2EFF  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
005B2F02  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
005B2F05  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax  
    25:             int y = a - b;
005B2F08  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
005B2F0B  sub         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
005B2F0E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  
    26:             int z = b - a;
005B2F11  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
005B2F14  sub         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
005B2F17  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax  
    27:             int w = 2*b + 2*a;
005B2F1A  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
005B2F1D  add         eax,eax  
005B2F1F  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
    27:             int w = 2*b + 2*a;
005B2F22  add         edx,edx  
005B2F24  add         eax,edx  
005B2F26  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],eax  
    28:             return x + y + z + w;
005B2F29  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-44h]  
005B2F2C  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-48h]  
005B2F2F  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
005B2F32  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-50h]  
005B2F35  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],eax  
005B2F38  nop  
005B2F39  jmp         005B2F3B  
    29:         }
005B2F3B  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-54h]  
005B2F3E  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]  
005B2F41  pop         ebx  
005B2F42  pop         esi  
005B2F43  pop         edi  
005B2F44  pop         ebp  
005B2F45  ret         4
```

Why there is such a big prologue? My windows is 32-bit. The project target is .net 4.5. Debug is On and Optimize is OFF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't run the application from the debugger. Instead, put something like `Debugger.Launch` into the code and run without debugging. The JIT compiler optimizes for debugging when you launch in a debugger, you want to avoid that here.

Running the 32-bit debug version in a debugger, I get

```
002E2EC2  in          al,dx  
002E2EC3  push        edi  
002E2EC4  push        esi  
002E2EC5  push        ebx  
002E2EC6  sub         esp,48h  
002E2EC9  mov         esi,ecx  
002E2ECB  lea         edi,[ebp-38h]  
002E2ECE  mov         ecx,0Bh  
002E2ED3  xor         eax,eax  
002E2ED5  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
002E2ED7  mov         ecx,esi  
002E2ED9  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],ecx  
002E2EDC  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],edx  
002E2EDF  cmp         dword ptr ds:[28C670h],0  
002E2EE6  je          002E2EED  
002E2EE8  call        730FCB2D  
002E2EED  xor         edx,edx  
002E2EEF  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],edx  
002E2EF2  xor         edx,edx  
002E2EF4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],edx  
002E2EF7  xor         edx,edx  
002E2EF9  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],edx  
002E2EFC  xor         edx,edx  
002E2EFE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],edx  
002E2F01  xor         edx,edx  
002E2F03  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],edx  
002E2F06  nop  
            int x = a + b;
002E2F07  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
002E2F0A  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
002E2F0D  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax  
            int y = a - b;
002E2F10  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
            int y = a - b;
002E2F13  sub         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
002E2F16  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  
            int z = b - a;
002E2F19  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
002E2F1C  sub         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
002E2F1F  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax  
            int w = 2 * b + 2 * a;
002E2F22  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
002E2F25  add         eax,eax  
002E2F27  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
002E2F2A  add         edx,edx  
002E2F2C  add         eax,edx  
002E2F2E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],eax  
            return x + y + z + w;
002E2F31  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-44h]  
002E2F34  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-48h]  
002E2F37  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
002E2F3A  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-50h]  
002E2F3D  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],eax  
002E2F40  nop  
002E2F41  jmp         002E2F43
```

Close enough to your disassembly. 64-bit makes this a lot better, but running release version outside of the debugger yields a much nicer... eh, actually, the whole method is inlined. Oops :) That's really the only case that should matter to you when you're dealing with .NET performance - the sample is something you'll not see in reality outside of a debugger. In production reality, there's no reason to allocate any variables at all, and more importantly, even if you use variables, they aren't necessarily on the stack. Don't confuse the .NET virtual machine (where everything is passed on the stack) with the actual code executing on the x86 "virtual machine" :P

Okay, so 32-bit debug version, outside of a debugger:

```
00350543  sub         esp,20h  
00350546  xor         eax,eax  
00350548  mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],eax  
0035054B  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx  
0035054E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],edx  
00350551  cmp         dword ptr ds:[1D4268h],0  
00350558  je          0035055F  
0035055A  call        730FCB2D  
0035055F  xor         edx,edx  
00350561  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],edx  
00350564  xor         edx,edx  
00350566  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],edx  
00350569  xor         edx,edx  
0035056B  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],edx  
0035056E  xor         edx,edx  
00350570  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],edx  
00350573  xor         edx,edx  
00350575  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],edx  
00350578  nop  
            Debugger.Launch();
00350579  call        725B0220  
0035057E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],eax  
00350581  nop  
            Debugger.Break();
00350582  call        725B0178  
00350587  nop  

            int x = a + b;
00350588  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  

            int x = a + b;
0035058B  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
0035058E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax  
            int y = a - b;
00350591  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
00350594  sub         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
00350597  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax  
            int z = b - a;
0035059A  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
0035059D  sub         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
003505A0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax  
            int w = 2 * b + 2 * a;
003505A3  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
003505A6  add         eax,eax  
003505A8  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
003505AB  add         edx,edx  
003505AD  add         eax,edx  
003505AF  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax  
            return x + y + z + w;
003505B2  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
003505B5  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
003505B8  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
003505BB  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
003505BE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax  
003505C1  nop  
003505C2  jmp         003505C4
```

You see that this is quite a bit shorter than the "attached debugger" version, but not quite as simple as the sample either. Most likely, this has something to do with various new features added to .NET or the JIT compiler done over the time. But it's still mostly academical - this is unoptimized code, specifically designed for ease of debugging. It's the same with the sample in the first place - it's an idealized situation specifically for showing off some concepts, with a few cases of weirdness (when was the last time you've seen a stack that fills from the bottom?).

If you're curious about the real x86 code in the 64-bit release version outside of a debugger, it looks like this:

```
000007FE94220495  xor         esi,esi  
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
000007FE94220497  xor         edi,edi  
            {
                sum += testCall.Calculation(5, 6);
000007FE94220499  call        000007FEF2FB7AB0  
000007FE9422049E  call        000007FEF2FB79C0  
000007FE942204A3  add         esi,21h  
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
000007FE942204A6  inc         edi  
000007FE942204A8  cmp         edi,5  
000007FE942204AB  jl          000007FE94220499  
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
000007FE942204AD  mov         ecx,esi  
000007FE942204AF  call        000007FEF2FBAC10  
000007FE942204B4  nop  
000007FE942204B5  add         rsp,28h  
000007FE942204B9  pop         rsi  
000007FE942204BA  pop         rdi  
000007FE942204BB  ret
```

So, how does it work? You can ignore the two calls in the loop - those are `Debugger.Launch` and `Debugger.Break` respectively. The whole body of the loop is just the

```
000007FE942204A3  add         esi,21h
```

Uh? Increment the `sum` variable (note how it's not on the stack) by 21h?

Let's analyze our function:

```
x + y == 2 * a
(x + y + z) == a + b
(x + y + z + w) == 3 * a + 3 * b
```

`a` is always 5 and `b` is always 6, so the function always returns 33, which is 21h. So, the compiler is "smart enough", but it's not very useful for judging function calls in .NET.

Let's make the method public, so that it *must* be part of the outside contract, and the code can no longer assume only the actual arguments that are passed are valid. Running again outside of debugger, we get... the exact same thing. The compiler *will* compile the public method, but it will still inline the solution where *we* use it, because that's still 100% safe.

Okay, let's make the arguments variable by reading them from input :) The function is still inlined. There's just no sense in *not* inlining the method. How can we force the code to avoid inlining? Well we could make the method `virtual`, so the compiler can't be certain what method is really going to be called, preventing inlining. Alternatively, you can use JIT attributes like `NoInlining`:

```
            Debugger.Launch();
000007FE94220530  push        rdi  
000007FE94220531  push        rsi  
000007FE94220532  sub         rsp,28h  
000007FE94220536  mov         esi,edx  
000007FE94220538  mov         edi,r8d  
000007FE9422053B  call        000007FEF2FB7AB0  
            Debugger.Break();
000007FE94220540  call        000007FEF2FB79C0  

            int x = a + b;
000007FE94220545  mov         eax,esi  
000007FE94220547  sub         eax,edi  
000007FE94220549  mov         edx,edi  
000007FE9422054B  sub         edx,esi  
000007FE9422054D  mov         ecx,esi  
000007FE9422054F  shl         ecx,1  
000007FE94220551  lea         ecx,[rcx+rdi*2]  
000007FE94220554  lea         r8d,[rsi+rdi]  
000007FE94220558  add         eax,r8d  
000007FE9422055B  add         eax,edx  
000007FE9422055D  add         eax,ecx  
000007FE9422055F  add         rsp,28h  
000007FE94220563  pop         rsi  
000007FE94220564  pop         rdi  
000007FE94220565  ret
```

Depending on your definition, there either is no prologue, or the prologue consists exclusively of preserving the few registers we use in the method - the 64-bit calling convention helps quite a bit here, but fundamentally the compiler just tries to find the cheapest way of doing what it has to do - in this case, it avoids using the stack entirely, and all arguments are passed through registers. Why is it even adjusting `rsp`? I don't know. Maybe it's something to help with debugging or exception handling? I can offer nothing but guesses on this matter. But it certainly has no bearing on the normal operation of the function. The moves that follow (moving arguments to other registers) are tailored to my CPU (a 2012 Xeon) - it allows for better pipelining. I'm not sure how the heuristic works and how much it tries to target specific CPUs or CPU families, but it certainly works great for my system :) It's the kind of code you would expect to be slower than the manual naïve assembly, but it isn't. Pipelining and branch prediction are the most important factors for CPU throughput nowadays, and in the naïve solution, they make the CPU stall quite a bit.

Let's analyze a bit. First, the compiler no longer tries to simplify the expression - it does actually evaluate x, y, z and w separately. However, you can see that it *still* doesn't use the stack for the variables (though it would possibly use the stack to *pass* the two arguments in 32-bit). `esi` contains b, and `edi` contains a; so we first do `b - a`, then `a - b` - simple so far. `eax` contains z and `edx` contains y. Then we put b into `ecx` and shift left once (`2 * b`).

But wait, what's up with that `lea`? The compiler actually abuses the CPU to let it do the rest of the calculation in a single instruction, while still optimally using pipelining and everything and spreading the workload over as much of the CPU as possible (on my CPU, the address calculation is independent of the "real" ALU). Pretty impressive, and possibly an example of how JITted code can actually adapt itself to specific CPU models better than pre-compiled code realisticaly can. Of course, those are the kinds of tricks we used with older hardware too, in hand-made assembly, but... impressive.

In short, be careful with your assumptions. Sometimes the compiler forgoes an "obvious" optimization, sometimes it's smarter than you'd guess. Whenever you're optimizing .NET code for performance, just make sure you're running the release version outside of the debugger, and make sure to profile 32-bit and 64-bit code separately - sometimes 32-bit is faster, sometimes 64-bit is.

Comment: Excellent answer. That's what I asked and more:)